# Can I stop the bottom menu bar from hiding when scrolling body on iOS10?

Tags: ios, css

When you scroll the body on iOS 10 Safari the bottom controls hide. Can I prevent that?

I need body to be scrollable.

Comment: What are you referring from bottom menu? Tabbar?

Comment: @Aisha Yeah the one with the nav buttons and such.

Comment: Then it should not be hide. Will you publish your code here?

Comment: add this code and then check

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView).y < 0{
        changeTabBar(true, animated: true)
    }
    else{
        changeTabBar(false, animated: true)
    }
}
You can also use the other callback method:

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    ...
}
but if you choose so, then you most handle multiple calls to the helper method that actually hides the tabBar.

And then you need to add this method that animates the hide/show of the tabBar.

func changeTabBar(hidden:Bool, animated: Bool){
    var tabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar
    if tabBar!.hidden == hidden{ return }
    let frame = tabBar?.frame
    let offset = (hidden ? (frame?.size.height)! : -(frame?.size.height)!)
    let duration:NSTimeInterval = (animated ? 0.5 : 0.0)
    tabBar?.hidden = false
    if frame != nil
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
            animations: {tabBar!.frame = CGRectOffset(frame!, 0, offset)},
            completion: {
                println($0)
                if $0 {tabBar?.hidden = hidden}
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean with regards to a website.

Comment: website you mean it is a server end issue?

Comment: No. Go to apple.com, scroll down. The bottom bar disappears. I don't want that to happen.